# how to map a value of Xml array to csv field

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <tXML>
      <Header>
        <Source>1</Source>
        <Action_Type>Update</Action_Type>
        <Sequence_Number>0</Sequence_Number>
        <Batch_ID>4</Batch_ID>
        <Reference_ID>043</Reference_ID>
        <User_ID>S</User_ID>
        <Password>password</Password>
        <Message_Type></Message_Type>
        <Company_ID>J1</Company_ID>
        <Msg_Locale>English (United States)</Msg_Locale>
        <Msg_Time_Zone>Eastern Standard Time</Msg_Time_Zone>
        <Version></Version>
        <Internal_Reference_ID></Internal_Reference_ID>
        <Internal_Date_Time_Stamp></Internal_Date_Time_Stamp>
        <External_Reference_ID></External_Reference_ID>
        <External_Date_Time_Stamp></External_Date_Time_Stamp>
      </Header>
      <Message>
        <DistributionOrder>
          <LineItem>
            <DoLineNbr>1</DoLineNbr>
            <ItemName>135465</ItemName>
            <Description>A</Description>
            <UpdateActionType></UpdateActionType>
            <PackageType></PackageType>
            <DoLineStatus>Released</DoLineStatus>
            <InventoryAttributes>
              <InventoryType>F</InventoryType>
              <ProductStatus></ProductStatus>
              <BatchNbr></BatchNbr>
              <CountryOfOrigin></CountryOfOrigin>
              <ItemAttribute1>R</ItemAttribute1>
              <ItemAttribute2></ItemAttribute2>
              <ItemAttribute3></ItemAttribute3>
              <ItemAttribute4></ItemAttribute4>
              <ItemAttribute5></ItemAttribute5>
            </InventoryAttributes>
            <Comment>
              <NoteType>MB</NoteType>
              <NoteCode>20</NoteCode>
              <CommentText>[JPY_ _Mens_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ]</CommentText>
              <Visibility>0</Visibility>
            </Comment>
            <Comment>
              <NoteType>MB</NoteType>
              <NoteCode>13</NoteCode>
              <CommentText>[ _00016000.00000_.00000_.00000_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ]</CommentText>
              <Visibility>0</Visibility>
            </Comment>
            <Comment>
              <NoteType>SC</NoteType>
              <NoteCode>02</NoteCode>
              <CommentText>[ _ _ _ _R]</CommentText>
              <Visibility>0</Visibility>
            </Comment>
          </LineItem>
          <LineItem>
            <DoLineNbr>2</DoLineNbr>
            <ItemName>4550155140404</ItemName>
            <Description>AS LAMBSWOOL VNECK</Description>
            <UpdateActionType></UpdateActionType>
            <PackageType></PackageType>
            <DoLineStatus>Released</DoLineStatus>
            <InventoryAttributes>
              <InventoryType>F</InventoryType>
              <ProductStatus></ProductStatus>
              <BatchNbr></BatchNbr>
              <CountryOfOrigin></CountryOfOrigin>
              <ItemAttribute1>R</ItemAttribute1>
              <ItemAttribute2></ItemAttribute2>
              <ItemAttribute3></ItemAttribute3>
              <ItemAttribute4></ItemAttribute4>
              <ItemAttribute5></ItemAttribute5>
            </InventoryAttributes>
            <Comment>
              <NoteType>MB</NoteType>
              <NoteCode>20</NoteCode>
              <CommentText>[JPY_ _Mens_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ]</CommentText>
              <Visibility>0</Visibility>
            </Comment>
            <Comment>
              <NoteType>MB</NoteType>
              <NoteCode>13</NoteCode>
              <CommentText>[ _00016000.00000_.00000_.00000_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ]</CommentText>
              <Visibility>0</Visibility>
            </Comment>
            <Comment>
              <NoteType>SC</NoteType>
              <NoteCode>02</NoteCode>
              <CommentText>[ _ _ _ _R]</CommentText>
              <Visibility>0</Visibility>
            </Comment>
            </LineItem>
        </DistributionOrder>
      </Message>
    </tXML>
```

I'm mapping above XMl to CSV pipe de-limited foramt and need help on how to loop LineItem-Comment and and check NoteType and NoteCode and print CommentText value.

Here is my condition

```
Loop Over  /tXML/Message/DistributionOrder/LineItem/Comment 
If
/tXML/Message/DistributionOrder/LineItem/Comment/NoteType = SC and /tXML/Message/DistributionOrder/LineItem/Comment/NoteCode = 02
Then
Remove start and end index of /tXML/Message/DistributionOrder/LineItem/Comment/CommentText
```

my dataweave to csv looks like this

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv header = false , separator = "|" , quoteValues = false
---
payload.tXML.Message.DistributionOrder.*LineItem map ((LineItem , indexofLineItem) ->  {

column_1: "000000002",
    column_2: (payload.tXML.Message.DistributionOrder.ProcessInfo.RefTextField8 splitBy "_")[0] replace "[" with "",
    column_3: if(payload.tXML.Message.DistributionOrder.ProcessInfo.RefNumberField1 != null) (payload.tXML.Message.DistributionOrder.ProcessInfo.RefNumberField1) else "00000000",
    column_4:"",
    column_5:"",
    column_6: "",
    column_7: "",
    column_8: "",
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    coulmn_56: ?(
    If
/tXML/Message/DistributionOrder/LineItem/Comment/NoteType = SC and /tXML/Message/DistributionOrder/LineItem/Comment/NoteCode = 02
Then
Remove start and end index of /tXML/Message/DistributionOrder/LineItem/Comment/CommentText)



})
```

I need mapping for column_56.

Comment: please add expected output for just column_56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the mapping to get you the commentText, I'm not sure what you're asking for.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv header = false , separator = "|" , quoteValues = false
---
payload.tXML.Message.DistributionOrder.*LineItem map ((LineItem , indexofLineItem) -> {
    column_1: "000000002",
    column_56: (LineItem.*Comment[?($.NoteType == 'SC' and $.NoteCode == '02')][0].CommentText) replace "[" with "" replace "]" with ""
})
```

Comment: could you please guide me how to get value R from the commentText <CommentText>[ _ _ _ _R]</CommentText>

Comment: I updated the answer to remove the square brackets from the text. Let me know if you have any other questions. Otherwise, please mark the answer as correct. Thanks!

Comment: Above code is printing  _ _ _ _R like this but i'm looking for just R could you please let me know how to retrieve this.

Comment: Actually Split the value of CommentText with symbol underscore '_'
and Map  the Fifth Value

Comment: What would be expected from this string in your example: `[JPY_ _Mens_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ]`

Comment: i have to map each value from that example, Anyways figured it out utechtzs. for getting JPY from above example i wrote like this (LineItem.*Comment[?($.NoteType == 'MB' and $.NoteCode == '20')][0].CommentText splitBy "_"  )[0] replace "[" with "" replace "]" with "",